# Сохранить компрессию UIImageJPEGRepresentation

Tags: ios, swift, изображения, compression

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане!
Нашел код компрессии изображения, что приведен ниже.

```
func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

func resizedTo1MB() -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0) else {return nil}

    var resizingImage = self
    var imageSizeKB = Double((imageData.count)) / 1000.0 // ! Or devide for 1024 if you need KB but not kB

    while imageSizeKB > 150 { // ! Or use 1024 if you need KB but not kB
        let resizedImage = resizingImage.resized(withPercentage: 0.9)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage!, 0.5)

        resizingImage = resizedImage!
        imageSizeKB = Double((imageData?.count)!) / 1000.0
        print("imageSizeKb = ", imageSizeKB)// ! Or devide for 1024 if you need KB but not kB
        print("resizingImage.width = ", resizingImage.size.width, ", resizingImage.height = ", resizingImage.size.height)
    }

    let compressionImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizingImage, 0.5)
    return UIImage(data: compressionImageData!)
}
```

}

Дело в том, что цикл перестает работать, когда изображение сожмется до 150 кб. В логах отчетливо видно, что цикл прекращается именно в этот момент! Изображение весит <150 кб., ширина: >1000 px, длинна: >1100 px.

```
for element in self.imgArray{
            let oldImage = element
            let imageData =  Data(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(oldImage, 1.0)!)
            let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            let resizedImage = newImage?.resizedTo1MB()
            print("resizedImage: do something with image")
            let dataResizedImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage!)
            print("imageData = ", Double((imageData.count)) / 1000.0)
            print("dataResizedImage = ", Double((dataResizedImage?.count)!) / 1000.0)
            newImgArray.append(/*compressImageWhatsApp(image: newImage!)*/resizedImage!)
        }
```

Но дело в том, что когда я возвращаю изображение, то в исходном коде в верху видно, что при передаче на сервер(переменная dataResizedImage) оно весит больше 1500 кб. Я не могу понять с чем это связанно, если кто знает, как исправить эту ситуацию буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что метод, который выполняет сжатие, для подсчета размера картинки внутри цикла использует формат JPEG и сжимает с сохранением 50% качества (второй параметр в методе `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Вы же полученную картинку передаете в формате PNG. Поэтому у вас такой результат.

Либо измените в последнем куске кода получение `dataResizedImage` на такое:

```
let dataResizedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage!, 0.5)
```

Либо в методе `resizedTo1MB` замените использование `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` на `UIImagePNGRepresentation` (обратите внимание, что у последнего только один параметр - сжимаемое изображение)